# ideviceinstaller fails with "Could not connect to lockdownd. Exiting."

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I try to use ideviceinstaller, the command fails with the following error message:

```
"Could not connect to lockdownd. Exiting."
```

Example commands:

```
ideviceinstaller -l
ideviceinstaller -i Something.ipa
```

I have googled more than an hour to find the solution, however nothing worked for me:

```
Reinstall ideviceinstaller
Reinstall libimobiledevice
```

Reinstall brew and reinstall again both ideviceinstaller, libimobiledevice
It works only if I use sudo but it's unfortunately not acceptable in my case.

**System paramereters:**
MacBookPro with 10.11.5 OSX El Capitan
Target devices: iPhone 5, iPad 2

**Note:**
I have installed both Xcode 7.3.1 and Xcode 8 beta 3 on my computer. And used these commands to switch between them:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the answer. This command will add durable privileges to use ideviceinstaller:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/
```

Comment: Wow this was the source of all my problems, lying behind cryptic errors that didn't make sense even to an experienced colleague.  But that fixed it.  THANK YOU!!!!!!

Answer (score 9):

Just FYI: updates to macOS, iTunes, and probably other Apple software will (correctly) reset the permissions on /var/db/lockdown.

The best solution here is to get the latest libimobiledevice, which has a fix for this particular issue:

```
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew link --overwrite libimobiledevice
brew install ideviceinstaller
brew link --overwrite ideviceinstaller
```

Answer (score 3):

When you try this command:

```
ideviceinstaller -d -i Something.ipa
```

you will get a detailed error. In my case the error is:

```
lockdown.c:218 lockdown_check_result(): ERROR: PairingDialogResponsePending
11:28:09 lockdown.c:1012 lockdownd_do_pair(): Pair failure
Could not connect to lockdownd. 
Exiting.
```

On further searching for this error no. 2 I found that there was a trust issue in the Iphone connected, so I opened the Iphone and gave trust device, then the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had many problems with `ideviceinstaller` too, so at least I have started to use `cfgutil`.

It's a CLI tool of Apple Configurator 2, always up-to-date and reliable, works well with iOS beta versions.

Just download the free app from the App Store: [https://itunes.apple.com/hu/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344](https://itunes.apple.com/hu/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12)

Start the app then select "Apple Configurator 2 > Install Automation Tools" from the upper left menu.

To install/uninstall apps:

```
cfgutil --ecid $ECID remove-app $BUNDLE_ID_OF_INSTALLED_APP;
cfgutil --ecid $ECID install-app $PATH_TO_IPA_OR_APP_FOLDER;
```

To get ECID, connect an iOS device and run the following command:

```
cfgutil list
```

Here are the available functions: https://pastebin.com/ZzeueLK2

Comment: This is a criminally overlooked suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, try first:

```
usbmuxd --force-exit
sudo usbmuxd -f -v
```

Then

```
ideviceinstaller -d -i Something.ipa
```

Answer (score 1):

bellow commands solved my problem

```
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew unlink libimobiledevice && brew link libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD  ideviceinstaller
brew unlink ideviceinstaller && brew link ideviceinstaller
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error while `brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice`
:

```
"configure: error: Package requirements (libusbmuxd >= 1.1.0) were not met:
Requested 'libusbmuxd >= 1.1.0' but version of libusbmuxd is 1.0.10"
```

Below commands will solve the issue:

```
brew update
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
brew unlink usbmuxd
brew link usbmuxd
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install ideviceinstaller
```

Answer (score 0):

use above mentioned command ->`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown/`

if the above command does not work then, remove files from lockdown folder

-> `cd /var/db/lockdown/`

-> `rm -rf *`

then try ->`ideviceinstaller -l`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the steps doesn't work. 
Finally, I find a way to resolve:

1. DISCONNECT your device!
2. run cmd in sequence:

```css
brew uninstall ideviceinstaller
brew uninstall libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install ideviceinstaller
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/db/lockdown
```

that works for me.